# Can I stop the execution of a function from outside that function?

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
function toStop(){
  while(true){}
}
toStop();
```

Now, how can I stop this? Or how can I kill the current thread if this function call is somewhere in the `setInterval` running thread? Example:

```
var id = setInterval(function(){
  toStop();
}, 1000);

//stop thread/timer with id here.
```

`clearInterval` doesn't work because it waits until the function call ends.

Thanks!

Comment: What is your while loop supposed to do? If you use `while()` wrong that function will never end as it will continue to do something `while` the condition is true so removing the interval will make no difference.

Comment: I believe the best you can do is have a global flag that allows you to break out of your loop.

Comment: JS is single threaded. When you execute that infinite loop, nothing else can execute until that function completes.

Comment: Technically setInterval runs the function every n milliseconds (1000 in your example), so it isn't "waiting" for the function to end per se, it is waiting to execute the function after 1000 milliseconds.

Comment: I think you need to elaborate on what exactly you are trying to achieve. What exactly are you trying to do within the infinite loop?

Comment: @plalx I don't think this is the same question at all. Would you care to elaborate?

Comment: Here is an example that does what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/amullins/29tyLhm5/. Since this question is closed (I could reopen, but I don't want to start a fight), I can't add a new answer.

Comment: @TravisJ `setInterval` does not guarantee that it will run every 1000ms. It will guarantee it will run at least every 1000ms. If I have a function that does work for 5 seconds without releasing execution, the interval will not fire 5 times but once after execution has been released.

Comment: I agree with Austin, while this question may be similar to the other in title, in content they ask very different questions.

Comment: @TheDude - It will attempt to execute, in that it will go into the task queue. Semantically you could call that not "running" but the browser does attempt to execute the code. Also, 5 seconds of code execution sounds a little excessive, perhaps there is an optimization opportunity :)

Comment: It is very excessive =)

Comment: @TravisJ 5 seconds is pretty normal if you're loading a video or a large image from a remote (or slow) server.

Comment: @AustinMullins - Perhaps it should be chunked in, loaded in an element, or buffered. What if it were 5 hours long or 5 gigs in size? Should the user wait for the related amount of time to load the entire video or image?

Comment: @TravisJ Now you're talking about UX. There's a whole other site for that :).

Comment: @TravisJ How is it different? The OP creates an infinite loop and asks if he can stop it afterwards, programmatically. That's just not possible, since the main thread will be busy forever. If the OP did ask how he could process some tasks without endlessly blocking the main thread, that would have been a different question.

Comment: @plalx - The linked duplicate asked how to stop the loop from an OS level, this asks from a javascript level. The questions are fundamentally different and the answers will be as well.

Comment: @TravisJ Ok yeah, I see your point.

Answer (score 2):

> "Can I stop the execution of a function from outside that function?"

**No**, you can't programmatically.

JavaScript is single-threaded and if you run a piece of code that makes it infinitely busy, such as `while(true);`, then nothing else will ever be able to execute.

Calling such a piece of code within `setTimeout` or `setInterval` will have the same result, since the callback of these gets executed in the only thread we have as well.

However, you can create a timed recurring execution using `setInterval` or `setTimeout`, which can be stopped.

```
var timerId = setInterval(function () {
    //Process an iteration of the loop in here

    //If you cause an infinite loop in here, you will have the same issue

}, 50);

//stop the timer after ~3 seconds
setTimeout(clearInterval.bind(null, timerId), 3000);
```

Notes:

- `4` is the lowest interval that could be honored as specified in the [SPEC](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#timers).
- `setInterval` will stack if the callback takes more time to execute than the specified interval. For that reason I never use `setInterval` and always use `setTimeout`.
- Timer intervals are not guaranteed to be accurate

e.g. with `setTimeout`

```
var stopProcessing = startProcessing();

//Stop processing after ~3 seconds
setTimeout(stopProcessing, 3000);

function startProcessing() {
    var timerId;

    !function process() {
        //Do some processing

        //Continue processing in ~50 ms
        timerId = setTimeout(process, 50);
    }();

    return function () { clearTimeout(timerId); }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of an infinite loop, just use an if statement and wrap it in an interval:

```
var shouldContinue = true;
var interval = 0;

function toStop() {
    if (interval == 0) {
        interval = setInterval(function() {
            if(shouldContinue) {
                ...
            }
            else {
              clearInterval(interval);
              interval = 0;
            }
        }, 200); // Or whatever interval makes sense
    }
}

toStop();

// ...

shouldContinue = false;
```

See this principle in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/amullins/29tyLhm5/).

Answer (score 0):

**No**, you can't programmatically, as @plalx said ***but you could try this***: declaring a binding outside and check on that to continue or stop the loop:

```
let letMeGoOut;
function toStop(){
    while(letMeGoOut != false)
}
toStop();
```

Here, I've created a function on `mouseover` that triggers a loop changing the opacity of the `h1`. It goes on till the mouse cursor moves out and is over something else in the page.

Here is the example: https://codepen.io/Mau-Di-Bert/pen/VqrRxE